# Place Order Button Gets Disabled

Tags: orders

I installed OPC and now I'm unable to checkout. So here's what's happening, when I click on "Place Order", the button gets disabled and the page goes nowhere. There is no order saved and the cart is still full.

I checked this in Firefox using the Console and everything happens fine, but it gets stuck at 
POST http://www.mywebsite.com/onepage/json/saveOrder [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 1340ms]

I tried increasing the Memory size to 256M in php.ini, but it still isn't working. Please help. Also disabled all third party extensions.

Thanks

Comment: What does OPC stand for one page checkout?

Comment: One Page Checkout .

Comment: Is it the default module or third party, if 3rd party which one? Have you checked the error logs, if so can you post the contents.

Comment: Please have a look in the [great debugging tutorial](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) and report back.

Comment: Check your browser's console log and see if there any JS errors.  See if the ajax post requests are returning PHP errors in the response.

Answer (score 1):

If you get 500 error, the first thing you need to do is to check your apache/nginx/php error logs. There you will find an answer or, at least, a waypoint for further debugging.